# Error in Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Below is a program for palindrome. If it is palindrome it will print YES else NO.
I am unable to understand what's the difference in calling:

```
> int n=Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine()); 

> or int n=in.nextInt();
```

because both is doing the same work.
1st one is taking `String`as input then converting it into `int`
2nd one is taking directly `int`.

when the 1st one is taken there is no error.
But when 2nd one is taken it gets stored in n then it prints YES.(when debugged  i found out that it gets stored in n but it skips the input string str and then it compares with str and s and prints YES).

So can anyone explain the logic behind this.

```
public class Test1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    //int n=Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
   int n=in.nextInt();
    while(n!=0){
    String s="";
    String str=in.nextLine();
    for(int i=str.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
        s=s+str.charAt(i);
    }
    if(str.equals(s) ){
        System.out.println("YES");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("NO");
    }
    n--;
    }
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that with Scanner you expect the String to be verified... in that case this line `int n=in.nextInt();` will throw a `java.util.InputMismatchException` exception if the input is not a number.

The verification would be easier to achieve by using `StringBuilder`, like this:

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
String original = in.nextLine();
StringBuilder reversa = new StringBuilder(original).reverse();
if (reversa.toString().equals(original)) {
    System.out.println("YES");;
} else {
    System.out.println("NO");;
}
```